# open new activity by imageview's drawacble id

Tags: android

I make a image Gridview in Mainactivity there is some images that named like image1.jpg,image2.jpg... and when someone click on image1.jpg then in fullimage activity the image1.jpg automatically opened and if someone click on image2.jpg then in full image activity the image2.jpg is automatically opened now in full image activity there is two things first is imageview and second is button
here is my mainactiviy

```
package com.cinegoes.www.video;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


GridView Grid;
GRIDAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    final Integer[] image = new Integer[]{R.drawable.image1, 
R.drawable.image2, R.drawable.image3,
                                    R.drawable.image4, R.drawable.image5, 
R.drawable.image6,
                                    R.drawable.image7, R.drawable.image8};

    Grid = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.MyGrid);
    adapter = new GRIDAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.grid_item, 
image);

    Grid.setAdapter(adapter);
    Grid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, 
long id) {
            Intent go = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Details.class);
            go.putExtra("image", image[position]);
            //By position Clicked
            startActivity(go);
        }
    });

}


public class GRIDAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Integer[] Image;
    private int resource;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public GRIDAdapter(Context context, int resource, Integer[] image) {
        super(context, resource, image);
        Image = image;
        this.resource = resource;
        inflater = 
(LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder Holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            Holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(resource, null);
            Holder.IMAGE = (ImageView) 
convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageID);
            convertView.setTag(Holder);
        } else {
            Holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }
        Holder.IMAGE.setImageResource(Image[position]);
        Holder.IMAGE.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);

        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        private ImageView IMAGE;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

here is my full image activity

```
package com.cinegoes.www.video;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;



public class Details extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle s){
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.imagedetail);

    Integer IMAGE = getIntent().getIntExtra("image", 1/*Default Value of 
Int*/);
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.images);
    img.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    img.setImageResource(IMAGE);

}
}
```

I have another three activities and i want when someone open image1.jpg and then in fullimageactivitywhen button clicked then activity one.java will be opened and if someone open image2.jpg and then in fullimageactivitywhen button clicked then activity two.java will be opened
please help me

Comment: just pass a position in intent and get it in fullimageactivity. then in fullimageactivity check if position 1 then open one activity or 2 so open second activity like so on

Comment: Can you add the code please